# Gazebo process dies everytime I roslaunch

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the error I get everytime I roslaunch:

```
Unsupported shadows type: "stencilAdditive". Supported types are "stencil" and "texture". Not rendering shadows.
Param [quickStepPreconIters] is deprecated: [replace quickStepPreconIters with stepPreconIters]
Param [quickStep] is deprecated: [replace quickStep with stepType]
Param [quickStepIters] is deprecated: [replace quickStepIters with stepIters]
Param [quickStepW] is deprecated: [replace quickStepW with stepW]
ScopedName[gplane]
ScopedName[desk4_model]
ScopedName[pool]
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 3857, exit code -11].
```

can you provide me with some help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12767/gazebo-process-dies-everytime-i-roslaunch/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on 2013-05-05**:
Hey i got the same error
How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "unsupported shadows type" message implies that your video card can't do what gazebo is asking of it. It should gracefully degrade, but it's possible Ogre (the 3d engine that gazebo uses) is mishandling the case and failing.

If you turn on core dumps with:

- ulimit -c unlimited

... then run it again it will put the crash information in `~/ros/core` which can then be analyzed with:

- `gdb --core=~/ros/core <path-to-gazebo-goes-here>/bin/gazebo`

That at least will tell you where it's crashing and then perhaps someone else can help more.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0